# Is there a way to conditionally import Excel data into SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an Excel spreadsheet with two columns: name and email.

I need to import this data into an existing table in my SQL Server database as long as the email doesn't already exist in the table.

I know I can write the SQL statement like this to check and make sure that the email doesn't already exist in the table.

```
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users
                   WHERE email = @email)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO users (name, email)
       VALUES (@name, @email)
   END
END
```

But using the SQL Server import data, is there a way to import the Excel data and then run this query before any data is actually imported?

NEW QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, email)
SELECT name, email FROM users_staging
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT 1 
                 FROM users 
                 WHERE email = users_staging.email)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The above SQL implies the file only contains 1 row, is that correct? If so, then considering you're only inserting one row perhaps you should just have a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the column `email`. Then the `INSERT` will fail if you try to `INSERT` the same value again.

Comment: @Larnu thanks, sorry no it is multiple rows...over 100.

Comment: Then I would suggest inserting the data into a staging table first, and then inserting it into your production table (not in an RBAR process like the above implies you're using). Or if you're using an ETL layer, must have some sort of look-up you can use to filter the data.

Comment: Side note: SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over 2 years; it is long past time you looked at getting your upgrade paths sorted. The longer you leave getting onto a (fully) supported version, the harder it becomes.

Comment: @Larnu thank you, so make a new table for the import.  I can understand that.  What do you mean by RBAR and ETL?  thank you

Comment: RBAR: Row By Agonising Row. ETL: Extract, Transformation, Load.

Comment: @Larnu if I have a staging table, can't I just use a stored procedure with my above code?  Or will that still not work?  thanks

Comment: The above code only deals with scalar values, it won't work for 100 rows.

Comment: @Larnu ok I think I finally understand, so I'd have to use my code above in something like a while loop...thanks!

Comment: No no no, don't use a `WHILE`...  That is a *terrible* idea. `INSERT` statements can process millions of rows at a time...

Comment: @Larnu is it my `IF NOT EXISTS` part that would cause issues?  thanks!

Comment: @Larnu I think I got it! Please look at my new query I added to my original question. Thank you for your knowledge!

Comment: Your new query is the way to go

Comment: You could load everything and delete dupes. You could use the email address as a Primary Key, because all emails are unique. So ,something like...

CREATE TABLE myTable(
    id integer primary key,
    email text UNIQUE
);